# Why doesn't the Delphi compiler warn for a redefined constant?

Tags: delphi, constants

A colleague of mine bumped into a constant that had suddenly 'changed value';
Turned out, it was redeclared:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

const
   MyConstant = 1;

implementation

end.
```

--

```
unit Unit2;

interface

const
   MyConstant = 2;

implementation

end.
```

--

```
Uses Unit1, Unit2;
// Uses Unit2, Unit1;

procedure TFrmRedefineConstant.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ShowMessage('MyConstant: ' + IntToStr(MyConstant));
end;
```

This shows `2`. If you swap the unit order in the Uses statement, it shows `1`.

Fine, but *why does the Delphi compiler not warn about the duplicate constant name* (That would be very helpful)?
Is there anything I can do to enable warnings (does not look that way).

Comment: it could but it doesn't, I guess you should ask on EMB forums as to why this is not raising a red flag..., the same applies to functions, classes, etc.

Comment: Why? Because it can also be a great asset to be able to declare a symbol/type with the same name in a different unit and put that closer in scope for the using unit than the unit in which the symbol/type is originally declared. Interposer classes for example wouldn't be possible without it.

Comment: @MarjanVenema true, however, some people would prefer being notified about this case in stead of hunting for bugs...

Comment: The only people who can answer that are the vendors of the product.

Comment: Time to create unit(s) just for constants ;-)

Comment: Nice example on why to keep things in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: *Turned out, it was redeclared.* Technically it was *hidden*. There was no re-declaration. There are two distinct declarations, one of which is hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of Delphi documented scoping rules. From the Language Guide:

> The order in which units appear in the uses clause determines the
>   order of their initialization and affects the way identifiers are
>   located by the compiler. If two units declare a variable, constant,
>   type, procedure, or function with the same name, the compiler uses the
>   one from the unit listed last in the uses clause. (To access the
>   identifier from the other unit, you would have to add a qualifier:
>   UnitName.Identifier.)

This is the expected behaviour since Turbo Pascal 4.0, which introduced units.

Comment: Yes, but *Why doesn't the Delphi compiler warn?* is the question.

Comment: Because it is a documented expected behaviour since 1987. Why should it warn about an expected and documented behaviour? Should it warn when a local variable hides an outer scoper ones? Or a class method hides a procedure or function? You'll get so many warnings they would be useless. In Delphi the unit declaration order **is not** irrelevant. Developer must list units in the proper order.
Sometimes people should read the official documentation about the language they use. Google or StackOverflow aren't.

Comment: Almost all compiler warnings do indeed warn about expected and documented behaviour. Compiler warnings can be controlled, switched on and off. The global effect of using a unit and the impact on name space is a humongous weakness of Delphi. Warnings would be valuable. But that's beside the point. The question asked a question that you simply did not address. The question is "why"?

Comment: Thereby every time you have "Uses Forms" it should warn you that TForm.Close hides System.Close?

Comment: Well, `TForm.Close` doesn't hide `System.Close`. It's the implicit `with Self` in a method of `TForm` or a derived class that does that. And the warning would be noisy if it warned for all potential hiding. But better would be to warn for an actual hiding. So you have to call `Close` from such a method in order to see the warning. But anyway, you appear unwilling to answer the question. Why did the compiler designers choose not to include such a warning. Please give citations in your answer.

Comment: You responded yourself. All those warnings would be noisy.

Comment: Not the way I would implement the warnings. Anyway, you don't seem to have grasped what I am saying at all. The question does not ask whether or not you think the warnings would be beneficial. The question asks why the compiler does not warn. In order to answer that with any authority you'll need to have some citations from the authors.

Comment: Then vote to close this question because it can't be answered, it's primarily opinion-based - as the FAQ says, and unless someone from Embarcadero drops-in (and I guess no one writing the original compiler is still there) noone can answer.

Comment: It's like asking why doesn't a police officer pull me over to warn me that my car is blue: it's not a warning. "Delphi compiler doesn't issue a warning because there is nothing to warn about". That is the answer to the question.